# Access Dynamics from a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I would like to program a Chrome extension that facilitates access to certain fields in Dynamics 365 CRM.

How do I get the formContext of Dynamics 365 CRM in a Chrome extension, or is there another way to access Dynamics from a Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the source code of Levelup, it's a famous extension (also for Chrome) and many functions are related to the form (like showing fields)

the repository is here https://github.com/rajyraman/Levelup-for-Dynamics-CRM

Comment: I know this extension, but i can't understand how dynamics is accessed there.

Comment: source code is there, if you want to create a Chrome extension connected to Dynamics I don't think you can find a better example than that repository